# limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}(\cos x +|x|+x)^{\cot x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to evaluate the following limit?
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}(\cos x +|x|+x)^{\cot x}$$

I tried substitution for $\cot x$ but got nowhere.
The result should be $e^2$

Comment: it is equivalent to $e^{\lim_{x \to 0}\cot(x)(\ln(\cos(x)+|x|+x)}$ and doing case work for $x\geq 0$ or $x<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x>0$, \begin{eqnarray*}
(\cos x+|x|+x)^{\cot x} & = & (\cos x+2x)^{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}\\
 & = & \exp\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\log(\cos x+2x)\right)\\
 & = & \exp\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\cos x\frac{\log(\cos x+2x)}{x}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
By L'Hospital's method,
$$
\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\log(\cos x+2x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\frac{-\sin x+2}{\cos x+2x}}{1}=2.
$$
It is known that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1,\quad \lim_{x\to 0}\cos x=1.$$So  as $x\to 0$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(\cos x+|x|+x)^{\cot x} & = & 
\exp\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\cos x\frac{\log(\cos x+2x)}{x}\right)\to \exp(2).
\end{eqnarray*}